# How to publish the windows 8 application to windows store?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-store

How to publish the windows 8 and WP8 application to windows store?
I use the visual studio 2012 to develop the application.
Please tell me some detials and the steps.
Thank you very much.

Comment: surely an internet search would answer this?

Comment: You can a have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/13/submitting-your-windows-8-apps.aspx

Comment: To be honest, I searched for a while and couldn't find that info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/13/submitting-your-windows-8-apps.aspx
Check this link... talks almost everything about publishing your app